# date condition to retrieve data in a 24 hour time window mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, perl, cron

I am using perl and DBI to query a mysql table. I need to retrieve all rows (aprox. 75,000 rows from 3 separate databases) within the past 24 hours, ideally between 12:00 am and 11:59 pm or 00:00:00 and 23:59:59.

I was using a `WHERE` date condition like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_name
WHERE insert_date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY);
```

Then I would run my script at midnight using cron. This worked well enough, but due to a regular large volume of traffic at midnight and the size of the queries, the execution time scheduled with cron is now 3:00 am. I changed my sql to try and get the same 24 hour period from an offset like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_name
WHERE insert_date 
BETWEEN DATE_SUB(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 HOUR), INTERVAL 1 DAY) 
AND DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 HOUR);
```

This seems to work fine for my purposes but I want to ask, is there is a more readable and more accurate way, using mysql, to get all rows from the past 24 hours ( between 00:00:00 and 23:59:59 time window ) once a day while running the query from an offset time? I am generally new to all of this so any critiques on my overall approach are more than welcome.

Comment: You really *don't* want a range of `00:00:00` and `23:59:59`. That way you will exclude any records created during the final second of the day. You may not expect any, but that isn't the point. You want everything between `00:00:00` up to but not including `00:00:00` of the following day. No, you can't do that with `BETWEEN`, but you *can* using `insert_date >= start_time AND insert_DATE < end_time`. Alternatively, in this case, it is *far* simpler just to check the date, ignoring the time. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume `insert_date` is a `DATETIME`?

It seems pointless to go to all the trouble of building two limits and using `BETWEEN`. I would simply check that `DATE(insert_date)` is yesterday's date. So

```
WHERE DATE(insert_date) = CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

Comment: @Barmar: I believe MySQL is more intelligent than that and, because the conversion of a `DATETIME` to a `DATE` is such a common one, it caches the conversion. But both your comment and this one are speculative and, unless you have any evidence, this isn't constructive.

Comment: Hmm, someone deleted my comment, which suggested that this form of query can't be optimized. Looks like it's version-dependent. I tried it on my own 5.1 system and it wasn't indexed, but sqlfiddle running 5.5 uses the index.

Answer (score 1):

```
BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY), "%Y-%M-%d 00:00:00")
    AND DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY), "%Y-%M-%d 23:59:59")
```

You could also use Perl date formatting functions to produce the same date-time strings, and interpolate them into the query.

Comment: This works really well, I just had to add `%` percent signs to the format string and use a lower case m, like this: "%Y-%m-%d ..."

Comment: @Borodin It's an easy way to get a specific time of the day. I don't think there's a significant performance impact, as the strings will be parsed just once for the whole query, then it will just do date comparisons (and if his `insert_date` column is indexed, this will just be an index scan).

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry, I was too hasty. I didn't notice that you were applying specific times to the date.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that `DATE(NOW())` implicitly means midnight this morning, the obvious solution is to take that value and subtract a day for the start... and subtract a second for the end.

```
BETWEEN DATE_SUB(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
    AND DATE_SUB(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL 1 SECOND)
```

Comment: `DATE(NOW())` is traditionally spelled `CURDATE()`. Also, I doubt if there is a special requirement to exclude records created during the last second before midnight. This is how obscure bugs are created.

Comment: There is absolutely nothing obscure about this.  BETWEEN is inclusive, so this does not exclude things created in the last second.  Also, using DATE(NOW()) allows any timestamp to be substituted for NOW().

Comment: It's a good idea to be precise about this. If the query is run every day, you don't want the records that occur precisely at midnight to be processed twice.

Comment: `DATE(NOW())` is `00:00:00` today, so `DATE_SUB(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL 1 SECOND)` (or, more clearly, `CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 SECOND`) is `23:59:59` last night. The `BETWEEN` won't magically include times between that and midnight, nor should it. If it does then what difference do you think subtracting one second makes? Do you suppose that, without it, it would include records until `00:00:01`?!

Comment: @Barmar: Yes I agree. As I said in my comment on the question, you can't do that with `BETWEEN` as it always *includes* the start and end limits of the range. Instead you have to use `time >= start AND time < end`.

Comment: The *obscure* in my comment refers to the bugs that would arise due to records created within one second out of every 86,400 being ignored, and not appearing in *any* report.

Comment: @Borodin The last second before midnight is being included, not ignored. Unless you think timestamps have more precision than 1 second, so it's ignoring things from `23:59:59.01` to `23:59:59.99`. But MySQL times are only precise to the second, so the last second before midnight will be included in the range.

Comment: @Barmar: That isn't generally true. MySQL version 5.6.4 and later supports up to six digits of fractional seconds. The OP doesn't say  anything about the `insert_date` field, but if it looks like `insert_date DATETIME DEFAULT NOW(6)` then your assumption is faulty. In any case, it is very wrong to write code that relies on the data having a specific precision. The correct way, as I have said, is to avoid `BETWEEN` and use `insert_date >= start AND insert_date < end` where both `start` and `end` are exact midnight times.

Answer (score 0):

```
....
WHERE insert_date BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 DAY
                          AND
                          CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 SECOND;
```

The lower bound will be coerced to yesterday's YYYY-MM-DD *00:00:00*, and this WHERE predicate will be able to make use of an index on `insert_date`.