# mySQL rows from today not last 24 hours

Tags: mysql, sql, date

Basically, I've got a query which looks like the following

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    `transactions` 
WHERE 
    `date` > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) 
AND 
    `status` = '1'
```

How can I do it so I can get it from just today, not the past 24 rolling hours; the same for a week & month etc..?

Comment: There is solution by `@Barmar`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20159859/542420

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `DATE()` to get the date of your date column and compare it to today's date using `CURDATE()`

```
WHERE 
    DATE(`date`) = CURDATE()
```

Comment: The one in question is more elegant and faster if it has an index on date column ,using your query index will not be used

Comment: Does it  DATE functions will obfuscate any indexes? [SARGable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable)

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan the one provided by  juergen d is SARGable and will use index if a column has

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid yes I understood, I am new to the concept so I read such query careful.  thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
SELECT * 
FROM `transactions` 
WHERE `date` >= curdate() AND `date` < curdate() + interval 1 day
AND `status` = '1'
```

which can make use of indexes to speed up the query

Comment: someone new don't understand this (I came to know few days back) so adding a link with your nswer: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable

Comment: Juergen can you suggest me a book on MySQL?

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: Sorry, I don't know a good book about it. And I did not read that in a book. I learn such stuff by answering and reading answers here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: No problem Jurgen, I think best is I should regularly read  from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql?sort=votes&pageSize=50) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/mysql/hot) :)